# Meaning of dimension in module finiteness.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, algebraic-curves

I am reading the book by Fulton on algebraic curves.In order to prove the weak version of Nullstellensatz they use some machinery.One of the definitions used in developing this machinery is that of module-finiteness.A module $S\supset R$ is said to be  module finite if $S$ is a finitely generated $R$-module and we denote the dimension by $[S:R]$.But I am confused about the meaning of dimension here.If it is the number of elements in a generating set of $S$ over $R$,then what is the guarantee that any two such spanning sets have the same number of elements.Is it something borrowed from commutative algebra?I am not sure.Please help me with this.

Comment: Does the book make assumptions on $R$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My copy of the book says:

> **If $R$ and $S$ are fields**, and $S$ is module finite over $R$, we denote the dimension of $S$
> over $R$ by $[S : R]$.

(Bold font for emphasis my own.)